# VBA IE getElementById not working

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm having trouble with getElementById it is not working properly. When i execute it doesn't wait till the condition is false.
This is my VBA Code:

```
If IE.Document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait").Style.visibility = "visible" Then
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
End If
```

HTML code

```
<DIV id=ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait style="CLIP: rect(0px 1914px 142px 0px); HEIGHT: 144px; WIDTH: 1916px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; FILTER: alpha(opacity=70); Z-INDEX: 1000; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 246px; VISIBILITY: visible; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white; opacity: 0.7" control="[object Object]" _oldDisplayMode="block"></DIV>
```

Or is there any way to define style tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for the page to load, use the busy method. Here's an example:

```
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object

Set wb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Address of site
wb.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/" 
wb.Visible = True

'Waits for page to load
While wb.busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

Does that help?

Comment: it's not working because my page is loading partially so when i use busy method the method not working as well as `wb.Readystate` method also not working in this scenario.